# Do we have a Japanese user we can send to CP+ 2012?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, events

The CP+ Camera & Photo Imaging Show 2012 is in Yokohama, Japan from February 9-12. More here:

http://www.cpplus.jp/en/intro.html

> Now, here in Japan, the home of photography.
>
> It is time to feel and witness the power of photography.

I think this would be a worthwhile event to send a Photo-SE representative to in some capacity. We don't have a very strong Japanese representation in the top users, unfortunately, unless someone has not filled out their location field. Can we find someone to go?

---

Update: the official announcement is now up at http://www.cpplus.jp/en/press/pdf/CP+2012PR_1130E.pdf. It looks very exciting:

- 50,000 visitors
- Exhibitions of cameras, lenses, accessories, software, etc.
- Keynote from president of CIPA
- Panel discussion on historical photography in Japan
- Panel discussion on video functionality in SLRs
- Talk by Elliot Erwitt
- Panel discussion by "top engineers from different manufacturers" (Olympus, Canon, Epson, Sony, Nikon, Panasonic, Ricoh) on the future of cameras

And more smaller stuff.

Panel talks from top camera company engineers and company officials, new camera models announced, lots of different topics.

Comment: Great suggestion! It would be awesome to have a PhotoSE rep at CP!

Comment: I might be able to add a link to this in our custom content area to give it more visibility. Does anyone have any objections to that?

Comment: Have you considered sending a user to The Societies convention in London.

This is the biggset convention for photographers in the UK. It runs in Jan http://swpp.co.uk/convention/2012/

Comment: @GraemeHutchison — sounds like a great idea. Suggest starting it as a new meta question to raise the visibility.