# Would it be worth while having a stand at the Societies Convention?

Tags: discussion

I commented on [this question](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1655/do-we-have-a-japanese-user-we-can-send-to-cp-2012) regarding a convention based in the UK.

The Societies is the UK's largest scoiety for professional and semi-professional photographers.

The [annual convention](http://swpp.co.uk/convention/2012/) is the largest photography convention in Europe.

Would members here be interested in having a stand at the next show (Jan 2013) which could bring new experts to our Q&A site?

Comment: Is it too late to send someone for January 2012, not necessarily with a booth but as a representative?

Comment: @mattdm I Have mentioned the next one is 2013, and yes a rep may be a good thing without a stand or booth. (as there is an obvious costs to these)

Comment: I'm confused, as the link you give says that the next one is Tuesday 10th January 2012....

Comment: yes, but this is obviously going to be missed. thats why I said the next show as the next one we could actually get to, as registration for this one (2012) is closed. There is no website for the 2013 one yet.

Comment: Looks like there's a few days left to register for the trade show portion at least — https://swpp.co.uk/secure/conventionform.htm.

Comment: yes, you can register as a visitor right upto the day. However would it be worth a person going who has been with the site for a while longer than me, and this may take longer to find than the cutt off date.

Comment: We've got several active members in the UK, surely we can get somebody.

Comment: Graeme, in theory, could you / would you go as a representative of the site, if no one else steps up?

Comment: well I could go (I am going) however I wouldn't feel comfortable as a rep as I have only been on this SE site for less than a month.

Answer (score 2):

Can some one at least please send Graeme some nice stickers and maybe a shirt?